# to get start and end time of application hosted in tomcat using javaagent

Tags: java, profiling, bytecode, instrumentation, javaagents

I have written a javaagent application to get the execution time of a java application and it works fine. i tried to use this application to get the execution time of a application hosted in tomcat server. i didn't get the required output. my javaagent code is from "http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jip/" .
I have two doubts
1. how to filter out specific application hosted in tomcat and profile using javaagent.
2. how does javaagent detect the start and end of an application in tomcat.

Answer (score 1):

Why does this need a java agent ? Use a [ServletContextListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) and record the time in `contextInitialized()` and `contextDestroyed()`.

From the servlet 3.0 spec

> Implementations of **javax.servlet.ServletContextListener** are invoked at
>   their contextInitialized method in the order in which they have been
>   declared, and at their contextDestroyed method in reverse order.

Comment: Probably sometimes the call to `contextDestroyed` is skipped by some containers !!!

Comment: I said sometimes , if you host tomcat 7 locally and start and stop it using Eclipse , you will face such ambiguity ;) its not about prod env though !